# How to change the resolution of an image?

Tags: go, go-gin

How do I change the resolution of this image before uploading?

```
f, uploadedFile, err := c.Request.FormFile("file") // image file
if err != nil {
    c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{
        "message": err.Error(),
        "error":   true,
    })
    return
}
```

**fullcode:** paste.ofcode.org/4wvAGNxZDmpqZ2Zucujmnw

Comment: You need to resize the image. The standard lib does not support image resizing, so look for a 3rd party solution (off-topic on SO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said icza you'll need an external lib to do that,
there is the basic : [resize](https://github.com/nfnt/resize) *which is no longer maintained*
and the bigger : [imaging](https://github.com/disintegration/imaging)

In both case you'll need to get the standard image struct before using a resize lib.

that would look like something like this :

```golang
import(
"image"
github.com/disintegration/imaging
[...]
)
[...]

f, uploadedFile, err := c.Request.FormFile("file") // image file

// Decode the file into a image struct
var srcImg image.Image
srcImg, _, err = image.Decode(f)

// Resize srcImage to width = 800px preserving the aspect ratio.
dstImage800 := imaging.Resize(srcImg, 800, 0, imaging.Lanczos)
```